# Vuex Data doesn't get updated on fetch when reloading browser (SSR) Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

**I found something about this bug I explained at end;**

Component codes

```
  async fetch(){ await this.$store.dispatch('bots/getBots') },
  computed: { ...mapState('bots', ['bots']) },
```

Store codes

```
export const state = () => {
  return {
    bots: []
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  UPDATE_BOTS(state, bots) {
    state.bots = bots
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getBots({commit}) {
    this.$axios.$get('url', {headers: {uid: '12345'}})
      .then(res => {
        commit('UPDATE_BOTS',res.robots)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
}
```

Issue: When moving between pages via nuxt-link data loads perfectly but when I reload the page bots state is empty...

**Found Issue:**
I use nuxt-auth and I had one plugin for checking status of axios request that if it was 401 unauthorized I logout user if he was loggedIn, So status undefined error was from here but I commented the plugin codes and I got other error from nuxt-auth that causes that problem I had So I related that issue in other question u can see it here:
[Nuxt-Auth Bug: Looks for autherization in any get request that has headers config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392522/nuxt-auth-bug-looks-for-autherization-in-any-get-request-that-has-headers-confi)

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools (mutation anywhere) and the network tab? Some error/warning?

Comment: @kissu I use nuxt-auth and I had one plugin for checking status of axios request that if it was 401 unauthorized I logout user if he was loggedIn, So status undefined error was from here but I commented the plugin codes and I got other error from nuxt-auth that causes that problem I had So I related that issue in other question u can see it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392522/nuxt-auth-bug-looks-for-autherization-in-any-get-request-that-has-headers-confi

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior. Vuex state is kept in memory and when you reload the page it gets purged.

Comment: I know how Vuex works, If u look closer u see in my component codes (fetch section) I run vuex action method that gets data every time that my component loads.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this state

```
export const state = () => {
  return {
    bots: []
  }
}
```

try this

```
export const state = () => ({
    bots: []
})
```

Comment: The first variant is totally valid.